# Trying to understand Markovian coupling

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

In http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vigoda/MCMC_Course/MC-basics.pdf at one point it uses $P(X_0, \cdot)$ notation, but I don't understand what does it mean.
I also don't understand how variation distance function ($d$) can accept $(X_0, \cdot)$ when it should take only distributions.

[image: markovian coupling]

Comment: The notation implies that the chain starts at $X_0,Y_0$ respectively and calculates the total variation distance between the distributions of the Markov chains at time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on AlexR.'s comment, the notation $P(X_0, \cdot)$ denotes the transition kernel of the Markov chain starting at $X_0$. In other works, it denotes the probability distribution of the Markov chain after 1 step. Here '$\cdot$' denotes a stand-in set. So for a set $A$ in the state space,

$$P(X_0, A) = Pr(X_1 \in A \mid X_0 = X_0). $$

Similarly, $P^t(X_0, \cdot)$ denotes the probability distribution after $t$ steps for the Markov chain starting at $X_0$, i.e

$$P^t(X_0, A) = Pr(X_t \in A \mid X_0 = X_0). $$

Once you understand this notation, you will realize that in the equation for the total variation distance, $d_{TV}(P^t(X_0, \cdot), P^t(Y_0, \cdot) )$ measures the distance between these two *probability distributions*. So you have two Markov chains starting at $X_0$ and $Y_0$, each goes $t$ steps, and updates the distribution of the Markov chain. This distance metric measures how far are these two Markov chains.